# I want to display data from the database to my jade template

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't seem to wrap my head around the concept of displaying data from my database into my front end ,The data is an array of objects and I want a single element from this array of objects.A sample of the data am pulling

```
{   createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 180000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 198000,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 210000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 231000,
    ActualRecovery: 5000,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 300000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 330000,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 360000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 396000,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 53000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 58300,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 78000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 85800,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 245000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 269500,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null },
  { AmountLoaned: 190000,
    ExpectedRecovery: 209000,
    ActualRecovery: 0,
    createdAt: null}
```

Now I need the AmountLoaned for the first object .

Comment: Can you add in some more data? I.e. database names, the array name etc. It will be easier to give you an answer then

Answer (score 1):

First you need to write the data you get into some variable. I'm not sure how you're getting this json data or if you need to parse it first but generally this is done like this.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(insertYourJsonHere);
```

Then it's a simple line

```
 var jadeVariable = jsonData.jsonObject[0].AmountLoaned
```

to select the first value and write it into 
your jade variable. And in your jade file you just type

```
p #{jadeVariable}
```

This will display your 180000 number in a paragraph.

Comment: We need more information, how are you invoking the json, what type of errors are you getting, etc...

Comment: Am pooling this data from a postgres database ,which am able to do ,the problem is that i dont know how to present a single element in my views

Comment: The way to select one object is exactly how I posted above, `jsonData.jsonObject[0].AmountLoaned` where jsonData is the name of the json that you get, jsonObject is the name of the set if you have one, [0] is the way to select a single element from the first set and .AmountLoaned is just the selector for Amount Loaned. I cannot tell you more because that JSON data sample is not enough, you have to post the whole JSON

Comment: I think i get u know ,Thanks @Amir Talic

Comment: Let me know if you made it, or if you need any more help.

Comment: I really appreciate your help,am a newbie in javascript thats why am asking some "silly" questions ,i owe you one.